# How to show utf-8 string in D3.js?

Tags: utf-8, d3.js

In [D3 Bubble Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/4063269), when I use Arabic characters as labels for the bubbles they appear as ���.

Is there a solution?

Edit: The HTML document has `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle out of your current code? Probably you just did not set your documents charset to utf-8. Use `<meta charset="utf-8" />` to do so.

Comment: Thanks Sirko! The HTML encoding is OK, but you reminded me to check the encoding of the file that contains the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the HTML document is in UTF-8, it seems that I forget to set the encoding of the file flare.json, which contains the chart data, to UTF-8!

Comment: Please describe **how** you set the encoding.

Comment: I think I just needed to save the flare.json in UTF-8 (no in ASCII) from the text editor.